# Visual Studio Code

Tags: visual-studio, mvc

Buenos días.
¿Alguien sabe si en esta nueva herramienta de Microsoft se pueden desarrollar aplicaciones en MVC e instalar paquetes nuget?

Comment: si estas en un ambiente windows podrías usar VS Community el cual es gratis solo se debe registrar, en otro caso, este link  https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/mt767698.aspx podría ayudarte

Comment: lo estuve viendo este fin de semana y si se le puede meter MVC